# C# program pass data to 3rd application program

Tags: c#

I have a 3rd application program and a c# program.

The 3rd app program need user to browse the filename, key in same password every time user need to upload the files.

The C# program is to get and save the folder source, destination path, and the password read from excel.

My question is, how can i pass all the data from the c# as input to the 3rd app program. Are it can be done? What method should i used? Any references are very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Process.Start.  You can find specific examples here:

[Dot Net Perls](http://dotnetperls.com/process-start-net)

Comment: try this one, but it seem i can only open/start the program but i dont know how to pass my data. but the no.6, startInfo.Arguments = "-f j -o \"" + ex1 + "\" -z 1.0 -s y " + ex2; i think it should be here right? what are the code means?

Comment: I go tru in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326952(VS.71).aspx, the passing parameter that mentioned here only passing argument which are the file name with the same extension with the application. I dont think this one can be use. Correct me if im wrong!! thx

Comment: Is it possible to pass arguments to the 3rd party application via the command line?  If not what method would be used to set the values you want to invoke the application with?  An example:

notepad C:\NEW_TEXT.txt

the above will open the NEW_TEXT.txt file in notepad, creating the file if it does not exist.

Can you give me an example of the arguments you want to pass to the application?